# It is safe to delete set free variables?

Tags: variables

For example I have followins line of code (usually I get these code from answers).

```
(projectile-global-mode)

; smerge-mode
(setq smerge-command-prefix "\C-cv")
(setq undo-tree-show-minibuffer-help t)
(setq undo-tree-minibuffer-help-dynamic t)
```

For each (`projectile-global-mode`, `smerge-command-prefix`, `undo-tree-show-minibuffer-help`, ...) I am having following warning: `assignment to free variable`. As I understand free variable does not have any affect on emacs's setup.

=> Is it safe for me to delete them?

Comment: The question isn't very clear - define "safe". What are you worried about, in particular?

Comment: The byte compiler is just warning you that you are doing a `setq` on a variable that it has not seen before. You can silence that warning by adding `(defvar ...)` for each variable (or you can ignore the warning). The part about "free variable does not have any effect" is not true.

Comment: @NickD , As I understand (since those variables could be seens as global variables) emacs will use them if imported libraries are using them, right ?

Comment: That is correct.